# In C++, what is the difference between std::something and ::std::something?

Tags: c++, std

When looking through C++ code, sometimes I see the use of `::std::ostream` instead of simply `std::ostream`

What are the extra two `::` needed for?

Example of `::std::ostream` use from https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values:

```
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& os, const Bar& bar) {
  return os << bar.DebugString();  // whatever needed to print bar to os
}
```

Comment: The only difference I can think of is if the current namespace also has a nested `std` scope.

Comment: Yeah, what @chris said. But almost always overkill, and generally not what most developers would do.